# How to load the contents of a url (not page) using jQuery, .load() and .get() aren't working?

Tags: jquery

The load and get functions work just fine when specifying a file like so:

```
.load('show_this_file.php');
```

but I need to load from a url like so:

```
.load('http://google.com');
```

Is there any way to get it to work, or some other function that's able to achieve this?

Comment: That's a cross domain request; it won't work.

Comment: You could use an iframe to load the page content, if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript has a [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) so you can not load another domain. You would have to use a proxy on your server to fetch the contents of that page.